# Javascript Closure and for loops

Tags: javascript

The code below returns: 
10
10
10
10
10
10
10....

How can I produce the following output?
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Here is my code:

```
function go() {
    var procedures = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      procedures[procedures.length] = function () {
        alert("You are now " + i + " years old");
      };
    }

    run_procs(procedures);
}

function run_procs(procs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < procs.length; i++) {
        procs[i]();
    }
}

go();
```

guide me please thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in self-executing anonymous function

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        procedures[procedures.length] = function () {
            alert("You are now " + i + " years old");
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: it worked! thanks how did it happen?

Comment: In your original loop, the `i` in the alert wasn't inserted as the current value, but as a reference to the original `i` variable. At the time when you were running `procs[i]();` in `run_procs` the `i` was already 10 and so it always printed that one number. By adding the self-executing anonymous function, we created a new scope and so every time `i` is referencing to one specific value rather than the end value (in this case 10).